# Model is null while POSTing to web api using fiddler (test)

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, asp.net-web-api-routing

Hi I have the below Model class for my project. I am trying to get Form values in my WEB API POST method in Values Controller, however the values received are null. I am here for your suggestion on getting the values as was posted in Form

```
 public class DetailModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set;}
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set;}
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

The below shown is the api controller code

```
 public void Post([FromUri] DetailModel model)
    {

            try
            {
                SMTravelsEntities st = new SMTravelsEntities();
                st.spTravelAPIDataCreation(model.FirstName, model.MiddleName, model.LastName, model.Phone, model.Email);
                st.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw Ex;
            }            

    }
```

I have tried both the [FromBody]  and [FromUri] for receiving the model data. However I am getting the null value in my "DetailModel".

Here is my code for Routes

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I have used fiddler to test it

```
{
```

"FirstName": "Sarath",
"MiddleName":"MM"
"LastName": "FF",
"Phone": "0000",
"Email":"s@s.com"
}

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
```

Host: localhost:1194
Content-Length: 103
Content-Type: application/json

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your fiddler?

Comment: A few workarounds and research gave me the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did to address the issue.

```
 public DetailModel Post([FromBody] DetailModel model)
    {
            try
            {
                SMTravelsEntities st = new SMTravelsEntities();
                st.spTravelAPIDataCreation(model.candidateFirstName, model.candidateMiddleName, model.candidateLastName, model.candidatePhoneNumber, model.candEmail);
                st.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                throw Ex;
            }
            return model;
    }
```